# How do you interact with js from dart?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

No, this isn't the same as the other question of the same name.

There are seemingly identical packages which seem to do this, but with different apis.

- http://dart-lang.github.io/js-interop/docs/js.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html

Why are there two?

Which one are we supposed to use?

The interop one looks newer and has a better api, but doesn't actually work. According to the documentation, you should be able to convert this javascript:

```js
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFFFFFF);;
renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 600);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
```

Into:

```dart
var pixi = new js.Proxy(js.context.PIXI.Stage, 0xffffff);
var renderer = js.context.PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 400);
document.body.append(renderer.view);
```

But that errors when you try to compile it:

```
dart2js
Error occured:/Users/doug/megac/client/public/dart/index.dart:7:27:
Warning: No member named 'PIXI' in class 'Proxy'.
var pixi = new js.Proxy(js.context.PIXI.Stage, 0xffffff);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So... js:dart? Is that what you're supposed to use?

Edit: Incidentally, for anyone who stumbles into this, there is also an open bug http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15795&thanks=15795&ts=1388068177 regarding how minified dart-js interop bridge operations don't currently work. The original issue was reported in May 2013, and there's been no action on it since then, so don't hold your breath.

Comment: The last error you get seems to prove that you forget to add `<script src="pixi.js"></script>` in your html page.

Comment: nope. It doesn't. In fact, js.context['PIXI']['Stage'] works fine, the documentation is just flat out wrong.

Comment: Ok, you are just confusing the APIs of [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html) and [package:js](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js).

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin Look, if you don't have anything useful to contribute, you can just say nothing. It's really fine, I don't mind. The documentation here http://dart-lang.github.io/js-interop/docs/js.html clearly shows using the blah.blah.blah syntax, which doesn't work. If you have something meaningful to add to any of the other questions, like: why are there two ways of doing this? Which one are we supposed to use?, by all means I welcome it, but you're just being unhelpful at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Js interop started with [package:js](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js). It was built with with [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

Later [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html) has been added to provide better performance and reduce the size of the compiled js file. Basically the goal were :

- removing scopes and lifecycle manual handling
- avoiding noSuchMethod to keep compilation size as low as possible
- renaming objects to make the api more understandable

Once *dart:js* has been ready, *package:js* has been rewrite to use *dart:js* under the cover.

*package:js* provides a simpler Api that comes at the cost of an increase of the js size (because *package:js* uses *dart:mirrors* and *noSuchMethod*).

Here is the same thing done with *package:js* and *dart:js* :

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

main() {
  var pixi = new js.Proxy(js.context.PIXI.Stage, 0xffffff);
  var renderer = js.context.PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 400);
  document.body.append(renderer.view);
}
```

---

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

main() {
  var pixi = new js.JsObject(js.context['PIXI']['Stage'], [0xffffff]);
  var renderer = js.context['PIXI'].callMethod('autoDetectRenderer', [400, 400]);
  document.body.append(renderer['view']);
}
```