# How to call jquery´s $ function in dart

Tags: jquery, dart

I try to make the following jquery functioncall in dart

```
$('#mytable').handsontable({
      data: data,
      minSpareRows: 1,
      colHeaders: true,
      contextMenu: true
    });
```

my dartcode

```
import 'dart:js';

void main() 
{ var data = [["", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Mercedes", "Mini", "Mitsubishi"],
              ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814]  ];

  context.callMethod('$', ['#mytable'])
  .callMethod('handsontable', [new JsObject.jsify(
  {'data': data,
   'minSpareRows': 1,
   'colHeaders': true,
   'contextMenu': true})]);  
}
```

The line:

```
  context.callMethod('$', ['#mytable'])
```

produces an error in the editor: Expected an identifier ('$' is marked red)
Any other string then the '$' semes to be ok, but the jquery function in $()

Comment: Did you try `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: You might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because `$` is the character in Dart String to perform [String interpolation](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.us5hu2wpthk4). To make your code work you have to escape this character `context.callMethod('\$', ['#mytable'])` or use a raw String `context.callMethod(r'$', ['#mytable'])`.

Answer (score 0):

thx @Intelekshual

```
context.callMethod('jQuery', ['#mytable'])
  .callMethod('handsontable', [new JsObject.jsify(
  {'data': data,
   'minSpareRows': 1,
   'colHeaders': true,
   'contextMenu': true})]);
```

works fine.