# How do I call a function on an element using dart?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm new to dart, and I'm trying to realize how to implement the following javascript code in dart:

```javascript
$('element1').handsontable(options);
```

*handsontable* is a third party library that I want to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call jquery´s $ function in dart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207439/how-to-call-jquerys-function-in-dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *dart:js* :

```dart
import 'dart:js';

context.callMethod(r'$', ['element1'])
       .callMethod('handsontable', [new JsObject.jsify(options)]);
```